# TypeVariable.getGenericDeclaration() doesn't return the type I expect

Tags: java, reflection

In the code below I expect `name` to be `BlackBox`, as this is the type of the `complex` field. But it returns `Pair`, which is the type of the other field, `simple`:

```
public class QuestionTest {
    abstract class BlackBox<TSimple, TComplex> {
        public TComplex complex;
        public TSimple simple;
    }

    abstract class Pair {
        public String one;
        public String two;
    }

    private String getFieldType(Class cls, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = cls.getField(fieldName);
        TypeVariable typeVariable = (TypeVariable) field.getGenericType();
        GenericDeclaration genDec = typeVariable.getGenericDeclaration();
        Class genCls = (Class) genDec;
        return genCls.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Test
    public void Test() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        BlackBox<Integer, Pair> blackBox =
                new BlackBox<Integer, Pair>() {};

        blackBox.complex = new Pair() {};
        blackBox.complex.one = "Uno";
        blackBox.complex.two = "Duo";
        blackBox.simple = 3;

        String fieldTypeName = getFieldType(blackBox.getClass(), "complex");
        Assert.assertEquals("Pair", fieldTypeName);
    }
}
```

Where's is my mistake?

Comment: _I expect name to be BlackBox_ vs _Fails! name is "BlackBox"_ What's up?

Comment: The type of the `complex` field is `TComplex`. That type is a declared in `BlackBox`. That's why you get `BlackBox`.

Comment: @Sotirios How can I get the type of `complex`?

Comment: You already have it. `TypeVariable typeVariable = (TypeVariable) field.getGenericType();` It's `TComplex`.

Comment: @Sotirios, but how do I get to its real type, `Pair`?

Comment: `blackBox.complex.getClass()`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks, but the point is to do it via reflection, while sending the field name as a string. I edited my question to help deliver the point.

Comment: `Field` represents the field itself as it is declared in the source code. It also allows you to retrieve a corresponding value for that field given an instance that contains it. The `Field` itself doesn't know anything about any instances or values itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part about your piece of code is the fact that you use an anonymous subclass here:

```
    BlackBox<Integer, Pair> blackBox =
            new BlackBox<Integer, Pair>() {};
```

This causes Java to retain some generic type information which would otherwise be lost. You can retrieve it using `getGenericSuperclass()`:

```
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) blackBox.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Class<?> secondTypeArgument = (Class<?>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    String fieldTypeName = secondTypeArgument.getSimpleName();
```

For a general solution, you have to find the index of the field's actual type in the `getActualTypeArguments()` array:

```
private String getFieldType(Class cls, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Field field = cls.getField(fieldName);
    TypeVariable fieldTypeVariable = (TypeVariable) field.getGenericType();

    int typeVariableIndex = -1;
    TypeVariable[] superclassTypeVariables = cls.getSuperclass().getTypeParameters();
    for (int i = 0; i < superclassTypeVariables.length; i++) {
        TypeVariable classTypeVariable = superclassTypeVariables[i];
        if (classTypeVariable.equals(fieldTypeVariable)) {
            typeVariableIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) cls.getGenericSuperclass();
    Class<?> actualType = (Class<?>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[typeVariableIndex];
    return actualType.getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how do I use it to solve this problem, of getting the correct field type

Comment: By removing ``String fieldTypeName = getFieldType(blackBox.getClass(), "complex");`` from your test class and inserting the three lines from my answer instead.

Comment: The key is using ``getGenericSuperclass()``, as you can use it to retrieve actual values of the type arguments, in the array returned by ``getActualTypeArguments()``.

The word "generic superclass" may sound confusing at first, but when you think again, the anonymous subclass is, of course, a subclass, specifically of ``BlackBox``, so this naming makes sense.

Comment: Ah - did you mean how to change the method ``getFieldType`` to return the correct value?